# Matches whatever regular expression is not inside the parentheses

Tags: python, regex

How can I match strings that are not inside a set of strings using python regular expressions?
Ex: set of strings ('/abc|/bcd')
I want to match any string other than that in the parentheses. That should be exact match.

Comment: Whats your desired output from `set of strings ('/abc|/bcd')`?

Comment: if I try to match any string other than this set of string it should return true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fun one for you:

```
^(?!\/(?:abc|bcd)$).+
```

It uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ensure that the string being matched isn't one of the strings you don't want, then grabs whatever else is left.

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/u5JssA/2)